# I can't build VSTO solution in 64bits windows

Tags: visual-studio-2010, x86, vsto, 64-bit, anycpu

I'm developing an Add-in for PowerPoint 2010.

If I try to build it with plataform target `Any CPU` or `x64` I get `HRESULT: 0x80040154 (REGDB_E_CLASSNOTREG)`

My solution uses a hardware dll provided in a SDK and one of its libraries .
I have already registered it with regsvr32.

I had similar problems before and always solved with regsvr32 but now it does not work.

I can avoid this problem building in x86 but when I try to run debug or release build in x86 I get the given assembly name or codebase was invalid. `HRESULT: 0x80131047`

I don't know what to do.

Thanks

Comment: same problem here using VS2012 and Win8Pro, need to build with x86 on a 64-bit machine, but get the "codebase is invalid" exception on add-in load in Excel (not on compilation)